# Installing Ubuntu over Windows 10 on a drive with only a few gigs of free space?

Tags: system-installation

I bought a cheap HP laptop just for the internet. Well, the hard drive is only about 30 gigs. Big problem, because so is Windows 10 with new updates. In fact there's not enough room on the drive to even update the operating system.

I thought, well, Ubuntu is much smaller. But I read I need 25 free gigs of disk space to install. Windows took up all that.

Is there a way to install over Windows or use an external drive, or USB?

Incidentally, I detest Windows 10 and want to move to an all-free platform with all free programs. That's something I can really believe in.

Comment: If you want rid of Windows, you can just select *Erase the disk and install Ubuntu* during installation

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing Ubuntu over Windows, you're overwriting the OS on the hard drive so all 30 GB will become available to Linux. Installing with a USB drive like you said will work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out in the next few days. Really looking forward to jettisoning Windows 10 and doing my simple computer needs on Linux and in a new environment that is much more appealing to me all around.